# Looping through object with hasOwnProperty check?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it pointless to use `hasOwnProperty` in the looping because object will always have properties?

For example:

```js
const fruits = {
    apple: 28,
    orange: 17,
    pear: 54,
}

for (let property in fruits) {
    if (fruits.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(fruits[property]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You use hasOwnProperty to only look at the properties declare by that object and not properties associated with the object it inherits from.

Comment: You're right, it's redundant. Unless you're looking for a specific property, it's just going to loop through the properties that exist.

Comment: `Object.hasOwnProperty` tests if the property for the given string key is not inherited (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)). In your case they are not, so it's indeed pointless.

Comment: Since you're iterating over every property it has and then check whether or not it does have it, yes. It will log  the value of those three properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're dealing with a plain object that doesn't inherit from another, such as with the code in your question, yes, the check will be unnecessary. When it'll be useful will be if you're iterating over an object which *inherits* from another. For example:

```js
const fruit = {
  isEdible: true
}
const apple = Object.create(fruit);
apple.color = 'green';

for (var property in apple) {
    if (apple.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(apple[property]);
    } 
}
```

In this case the `hasOwnProperty` check is needed to ensure the `for..in` loop only `console.log`s properties *directly on* the `apple` object - otherwise, properties on the object `apple` inherits from (that is, `fruit`) will be printed as well:

```js
const fruit = {
  isEdible: true
}
const apple = Object.create(fruit);
apple.color = 'green';

for (var property in apple) {
  console.log(apple[property]);
}
```

In the vast majority of cases, it's best to simply use `Object.keys` (or `Object.entries` or `Object.values`) instead, which will iterate over properties *directly on the object* (ignoring inherited properties):

```js
const fruit = {
  isEdible: true
}
const apple = Object.create(fruit);
apple.color = 'green';

Object.values(apple).forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

For your code, which is using a plain object literal that doesn't inherit from another (except for from `Object`, which doesn't have any enumerable properties), it doesn't make a difference - *but the functional Object methods* are still generally nicer to work with than `for..in` loops (which are forbidden by many [linters](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#iterators-and-generators))